mpi4py one-sided MPI test script
I am trying to install mpi-sppy and am stuck with running a basic test script to make sure that the one-sided MPI calls work. I am using MPICH on Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 11 by WSL2. The versions are mpi4py==4.0.1 and MPICH Version:4.0.
At line 49, I am getting an assertion error. After trying to figure out what might be happening, I found out that win.Lock(0) at line 45 is waiting for win.Lock(1) at line 37. Is this the way it should work - meaning that there is an error with the test script?
start = time.time()
if (rank == 0):
    buff[:] = 3. * np.ones(array_size, dtype='d')
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: going to sleep")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: woke up")
    buff[:] = np.arange(array_size)

    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: ready for lock")
    win.Lock(1)
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: locked")
    win.Put((buff, array_size, mpi.DOUBLE), target_rank=1)
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: Put")
    win.Unlock(1)

elif (rank == 1):
    buff = np.ones(array_size, dtype='d')
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: going to sleep")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: woke up")
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: ready for lock")
    win.Lock(0)
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: locked")
    win.Get((buff, array_size, mpi.DOUBLE), target_rank=0)
    print(f"rank {rank} - {time.time()-start}: Get")
    win.Unlock(0)

resulted in
rank 1 - 1.0728836059570312e-05: going to sleep
rank 0 - 0.00027298927307128906: going to sleep
rank 1 - 1.0001559257507324: woke up
rank 1 - 1.000209093093872: ready for lock
rank 0 - 3.000467300415039: woke up
rank 0 - 3.0005922317504883: ready for lock
rank 0 - 3.000704050064087: locked
rank 1 - 3.0007107257843018: locked
rank 0 - 3.002230405807495: Put
rank 1 - 3.002246618270874: Get


Win lock and unlock are strangely chosen names and do not what most programers would expect. They should certainly not block.

@Joachim It does seem to be blocking as shown in the updated post...

It might be necessary to enable asynchronous progress. Try setting MPIR_CVAR_ASYNC_PROGRESS=1.

@Joachim worked like a charm!
